# Обособление оборота "как завороженный"

Tags: пунктуация, авторская-пунктуация, обороты-с-как

Как объяснить обособление оборота "как завороженный" в следующем предложении:

*Я смотрю на всё это, **как завороженный*** (Б. Акунин).

Дополнительные вопросы:

Можно ли **без контекста** определить наличие вариантов и предложить их объяснение?

Как на обособление оборота может **повлиять** контекст?

Спасибо.